# javascript doesn't work to display alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, socket.io, polymer

I have an html element and i want to display an alert when i click on the "i" element. When the div with the class "innerNotif" is put directly on the DOM it works but when i add the div with the socket.on  it doesn't work. I think it s because the element is not in the DOM when it's load.

```
<span class="disNone notificationMenuCss" id="notifBar">
   <div class="innerNotif" id="idNatif">1<i class="fa fa-times" on-click="removeNotif" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</span>

<script>
var socket = io.connect();
var notifId = 0;

socket.on('libCourtLotChangeServ', function(){
        var numItems = $('.innerNotif').length +1;

    $( "#notifBar" ).append( '<div class="innerNotif" id="id' + notifId +'"><i class="fa fa-times" on-click="removeNotif" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>');
    notifId++;
    $("#notificationNumber").html(numItems);
});
</script>

<script>
    Polymer({
        alertNotif: function() {
            alert('Test');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you may be missing closing bracket of `append`

Comment: The end of the bracket is after the </div> element just before notifId++

Comment: @alexzerah the `</i>` and `</div>');` need to be on the same line. You cannot split lines within a string

Comment: Did you forget to register your element since you are using `polymer`?

Comment: @Ofisora what element does i have to register ?

Comment: @alexzerah is it possible to post your full code for this page including imports?

Comment: I finally find a way to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly find a solution by adding a onclick function of a parent element and add a addEventListener on it

```
<paper-toolbar class="header" on-click="removeNotif">
    <div class="notification" on-click="notificationMenu">
        <span class="notificationSpan" id="notificationNumber"></span>
        <span class="disNone notificationMenuCss" id="notifBar"></span>
    </div>
</paper-toolbar>

<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect();
var notifId = 0;

socket.on('libCourtLotChangeServ', function(contrat){
    var numItems = $('.innerNotif').length +1;
    $( "#notifBar" ).append( '<div class="innerNotif" id="id' + notifId +'" style="width: 96%; height: 30px; text-align: left; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white; padding: 3px;">' + 'Le contrat <br>' + contrat + ' a été modifié ' + '<i class="fa fa-times" on-click="removeNotif" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>');
    notifId++;
    $("#notificationNumber").html(numItems);
});
</script>

<script>
 Polymer({
     removeNotif: function() {
         var idValue = Number(($(".innerNotif:last").attr("id")).replace("id", "0")); 
         console.log(idValue);
         for (var numItemsCheck = 0; numItemsCheck <= idValue; numItemsCheck++){ 
             document.querySelector("#id" + numItemsCheck).addEventListener("click", function(){
                 var numItems = $('.innerNotif').length -1;
                 $("#notificationNumber").html(numItems);
                 this.remove();
              })
          }
      }
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The new line characters are breaking the string you want to append.

This should work:

```
$( "#notifBar" ).append( '<div class="innerNotif" id="id' + notifId + '"><i class="fa fa-times" on-click="removeNotif" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code which I was edited.

```
<span class="disNone notificationMenuCss" id="notifBar">
   <div class="innerNotif" id="idNatif">1<i class="fa fa-times" on-click="removeNotif" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</span>

<script>
var socket = io.connect();
var notifId = 0;

socket.on('libCourtLotChangeServ', function(){
        var numItems = $('.innerNotif').length +1;

    $( "#notifBar" ).append( '<div class="innerNotif" id="id' + notifId + '"><i class="fa fa-times" on-click="removeNotif" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>');
    notifId++;
    $("#notificationNumber").html(numItems);
});
</script>

<script>
    Polymer({
        alertNotif: function() {
            alert('Test');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I make the change but it's still not working, i don't get why

Comment: may be the error is showing from io object or polymer function. Other wise in the script all code is well running. probably socket connection mistake.

Comment: Thanks, i will see if polymer is the problem